# Retrieve UITableViewController static cell value

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` with fixed text. I add some level in each row and hence it is static, therefore I don't create an `IBOutlet` with the `UITableViewController`. When I tried to retrieve the selected value I always get `nil` in the `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method.

```
let currentCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!;
        print(currentCell.textLabel?.text)
```

I need advice. Please help me out.

Comment: Did you set the tables delegate?

Comment: Its a table view controller. In table view controller should I need to add any delegate ?